# how to correctly calculate the mean of a mat with "NAN" value in armadillo

Tags: c++, armadillo

```
#include <armadillo>
int main(){
  auto mat=arma::mat(5,5).fill(1);
  mat(1,1)=NAN;
  arma::mean(mat).print();
}
```

and the result will be 【1，NAN，1，1，1】.
But I expect armadillo to ignore illegal value like NAN，and get result 【1，1，1，1，1】.
what should I do？ Can anyone help with me? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: If a column contains any NAN, then the mean *should* be NAN. Perhaps you're using the wrong tool for the job? What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: just to get the mean of all legal numbers in one row

Comment: AFAIK, Armadillo does not have a switch that says "do this, but ignore NaNs".   To calculate the mean by hand, in general, add up the value and count the number of values.   When doing that, if a NaN is encountered, don't count it or add it.    One common test of a NaN is that it never tests as equal to itself.   Since C++11, there is also a function `std::isnan()` declared in `<cmath>`, with overloads accepting `float`, `double`, and `long double`   (there are also overloads accepting standard integral types, that work by converting to `double`).

Comment: @scirocc no, I mean that perhaps you're using the wrong tool for whatever task you're doing. Maybe NAN isn't the best representation of of an illegal number, or maybe a matrix isn't the best representation of your data.

Comment: @ Peter thx pal,I got it

Comment: @Peter I checked and there is indeed an overload for `std::isnan` for integral types. But should it always return false then. That is, NaN is not represented by integral types and thus when casting to double you will always get a valid number.

Comment: You may want to take a look at [NaN @ Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN#Floating_point). Buried in there is the statement *"Floating-point operations other than ordered comparisons normally propagate a quiet NaN (qNaN)."* That is, the expectation of the people who wrote the floating point standard is that `(1 + NaN + 1 + 1 + 1)/5)` will evaluate to `NaN/5` which in turn will evaluate to `NaN`. There is an explanation of why this approach was adopted in the article. (I'm not saying you have to agree with it; I'm just advising you be aware of it.)

Comment: @darcamo  -  When converting a NaN to a integral type, some hardware instruction sets produce a particular value (specific to each integral type).   If I understand the intent of the overloads of `isnan()` that accept integral types, those integral values on the particular implementations, can cause `isnan()` to return true.   [I've never had reason to test such things - I design to prevent NaNs occurring, rather than trying to respond to their aftermath - so have never looked particularly closely at what overloads of `isnan()` for integral types actually do].

Comment: Armadillo has a related function for finding non-finite values, which may help here: [find_nonfinite()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#find_nonfinite)

Answer (score 0):

We can use the submatrix views to achieve this goal.

```cpp
// Replace the NaN in the current column with the average
void ImputeColWithMean(arma::vec& col_vec) {
    // Get the non-NaN element index of the current column
    arma::uvec indices = arma::find_finite(col_vec);

    // Calculate the mean of non-NaN elements in the current column
    double col_mean = arma::mean(col_vec.elem(indices));

    // Replace the NaN in the current column with the average
    col_vec.replace(arma::datum::nan, col_mean);
}

int main(){
   // Here is the matrix
   arma::mat A{{1, arma::datum::nan}, {arma::datum::nan, 2}, {3, 2}};
   
   // Perform operations on each column of the matrix
   A.each_col([](arma::vec& vec) { ImputeColWithMean(vec); });

   return 0;
}
```